# LINQ: integer exists in array

Tags: arrays, linq, integer

I need to find all the records where the TestEventId exists in my int array. What is the good way to do it? Basically I am looking for:

```
 int[] testevents = McTestEventService.ReadTestEventsforTestCenter(testcenterid);
        var testcentercandidates =
            context.McTestCandidateRegistration.Where(m =>m.McTestEventId is in(testevents[]) ).ToList();
```

Suggestions? I can find a work around but thought may be I will ask if there is any neat solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int[] testevents = McTestEventService.ReadTestEventsforTestCenter(testcenterid);
        var testcentercandidates =
            context.McTestCandidateRegistration.Where(m=>testevents.Contains(m.McTestEventId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for:

```
.Where(m => testevents.Contains(m.McTestEventId))
```

?